# Basic jquery toggle menu for mobile not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a very basic toggle menu using jQuery's `on: tap` which isn't working:

```
<nav id="mobile-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        etc...
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="anchor">
    <header>
        <img src="menu-icon.png">
    </header>
</div>
```

Then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = "fast";

    $("#anchor").addClass("hidden");

    $("#anchor.hidden header img").on("tap", function() {
        $("#mobile-nav").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, speed);

        $("header").animate({
            left: "252px"
        }, speed);

        $("#anchor").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#anchor").addClass("active");
    });

    $("#anchor.active header img").on("tap", function() {
        $("#mobile-nav").animate({
            left: "-252px"
        }, speed);

        $("header").animate({
            left: "0"
        }, speed);

        $("#anchor").removeClass("active");
        $("#anchor").addClass("hidden");
    });

});
```

`#mobile-nav` is a div which is `250px` in `width` and is set to an `absolute position` with a `left` of `-252px`, which is then set to `0` when the image icon is tapped (making it slide into view). As you can see, once it slides out, it *should* remove the `hidden` class and add an `active` class. Then I set a custom `tap` function to slide it *back* and remove the `active` class and add `hidden` again. It will slide out, but not slide back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got it live somewhere ?

Comment: Try changing to a click event, and see if that fires. `Tap` is proprietary to jQuery Mobile, and doesn't exist in jQuery, I don't think.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, but I'm also using jquery mobile. Update: Nope. Still same result as `tap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have multiple events triggered on your image click. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = "fast";

    $("#anchor").addClass("hidden");

    $("#anchor header img").on("click", function() {
        $('#anchor').hasClass('active') ? left = '-=252px' : left = '+=252px';
        $("#mobile-nav, header").animate({'left': left}, speed);    
        $("#anchor").toggleClass("hidden active");
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fknCe/)

Comment: That's it! Thank ya very much. :)